# Knapsack algorithm with special objects

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I need to create algorithm for extended Knapsack problem, where we have special items with normal items and I can pack only several special items.

So, we have N items and we know weight/value/isSpecial of each one. Also we have defined S, which is maximum number of special items.

Any idea?

Comment: Please formalize it, and then check out if integer-programming is a viable approach.

Comment: Can you not treat the special items restriction identically to the weight restriction?

Comment: @myrtlecat No, you can not. You just have simple list of items with weights/values and knowledge about each item whether is special or not. You can work with special items just as with common, but each time you use special-one, you have to increase counter which can not exceed given number (usually small one)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the restriction on special items can be reformulated as a second weight restriction as follows: common items have a "special weight" of 0, special items have a "special weight" of 1, and the total "special weight" must not exceed S. Mathematically, the original weight restriction and the "special weight" restriction can be treated identically, and that gives @Codor's solution below.

Comment: @myrtlecat, yes, you are right. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be modeled as a non-geometric knapsack problem where each item has two weights (namely the actual weight and a second weight which is `1` if and only if it is *special*); the first weight capacity is the knapsack capacity and the second weight capacity is the desired maximum number of *special* items. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints) Wikipedia article, the problem is known to be `NP`-complete and does not admit an FPTAS unless `P=NP`, but admits an [FPTAS](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540402862). Apparently the two-dimensional version also admits a dynamic programming algorithm similar to the one-dimensional version. The semantics of the state space would be as follows, where each item has two weights `w1[i]` and `w2[i]` and profit `p[i]` and where `C1` and `C2` are the respective capacities.

```
P[i,j,k] := maximum profit attainable for items in {1,...,i} with weight
            in the first component at most j and weight in the second
            component at most k
            
            for any i in {1,...,N}
                    j in {1,...,C1}
                    k in {1,...,C2}
```

The recurrence relation would be as follows.

```
P[i,j,k] = max{ P[i-1,j-w1[i],k-w2[k]] + p[i], // item i occurs
                P[i-1,j,k]                     // item i does not occur
              }
```

In an actual implementation, some index checking would be necessary to determine whether the first case can actuallty occur.

Comment: nice answer, thank you. Could you provide code or more detailed pseudocode as well?